# Intercept WM_CLOSE for cleanup operations

Tags: c++, winapi, exit, termination

I have an external application that calls my application and is supposed to end it when the job is done.  The log from this external application claims it uses `WM_CLOSE` on my app.

How can I intercept the `WM_CLOSE` message in my application to do some cleanup operations? I tried `at_exit()` and wrapping it in a class, but I think I have the wrong approach.

Comment: Do you use some kind of framework in your application? Does that have an OnClose function to override?

Comment: Does your app have a message loop where you handle other Windows messages?

Comment: No, so far its only a consolse application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just handle WM_CLOSE in your message loop to do whatever cleanup is necessary, or even abort the close (by returning 1 instead of 0). See e.g. this: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/141438-handling-wm_close-wm_destroy.html#post1056273

Edit: for console applications, this may be of interest: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178893

Comment: Thanks for the links, i am interested in changing it into a hidden window application. Do you have any starting links for me?

Comment: This is older, but the code under "Message Processing" should be sufficient for a minimal application: http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson01b.htm

Comment: Ok, thanks for your support.

I found a good tutorial:
http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

Comment: If your console application is singlethreaded, you will have to pump your window message loop (call GetMessage,...) from time to time, and each time check if WM_CLOSE arrived. Other solution is to create window in seprate thread.

Answer (score 5):

The official solution for console applications is [`HandlerRoutine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), a callback set by `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. Windows will call your handler with a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` argument in case of a `WM_CLOSE` exit.

When you're using a class method with `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, it must be a `static` method - Windows won't provide you with a `this` pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, but I sucessfully changed it into a winapi application.
If its not working out this way I might try your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You must create hidden window using winapi, and handle WM_CLOSE message in its message loop. Is your app using any gui elements?

Comment: No its just a console application.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I think is to call [PeekMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from time to time.

```
BOOL IsCloseEventReceived()
{
    MSG msg;
    return PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_CLOSE, WM_CLOSE, PM_NOREMOVE);
}
```

This function should work to check if a WM_CLOSE message has been posted. It's not blocking, and you'll need to call it on a regular basis.

I might be wrong, but I think you don't need a hidden window to handle messages, a message queue is attached to your process the first time you call a messages-related function, like PeekMessage. However if you receive a WM_CLOSE message prior to your first call of this function it might be lost.

Comment: Ok, but then i need to make a loop which checks every 200ms for the signal, right?

Comment: Yes, or if you already have a loop in your code that's executed regularly you might insert it there (if the place gets executed too often you might add a counter and make a check once every 1000 times or something so you don't affect performace too much). That way you won't need to change your control flow.

Comment: Tried it. Works great! I already had a loop running so it fitted in with minimal changes. Best of all, it didn't need a hidden Window.